# how to change value in a range of cell to a data array in google AppScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to pull data in a range of cell and then push those values into an array of data?

In this code I tried to get those values in range E2:E97 and then push those values to an array such as [E2 value, E3 Value, etc] then set value to database sheet using dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1).setValue(value);

but it seems I can't get it done with those code. so any idea to do this?

```js
// Save Data

function saveData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("newform");
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("newdb");
  var dataBaseNameColIndex = 1;
  var formDataRange = ['E2:E97'];
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert(
    'Save Data ?',
    ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
    for (var i = 2; i < formDataRange.length; i++) {
      var value = formS.getRange(formDataRange[i], 5).getValue();
      dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow() + 1).setValue(value);
      console.log(saveData);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to copy and paste data cell-by-cell, you may want to do it in one go. That would be more efficient.

So instead of:

```
  var value = formS.getRange(formDataRange[i], 5).getValue();
```

you could use the following without the `for` loop:

```
  var allValues = formS.getRange('E2:E97').getValues();
```

And then post the data to the new range like this:

```
  dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow() + 1, 2, allValues.length, allValues[0].length).setValues(value);
```

I am assuming you want to paste the data into column 2 onwards. Adjust the 2nd value in `getRange()` above accordingly.

The 3rd and 4th values in `getRange()` above are the number of rows and columns to pasts.
`allValues.length` is the number of rows of data. In this case it would be 95.

and `allValues[0].length` would the number of columns in the top row of the data copied. And in this case it should be one.

I am suggesting this way as you won't need to keep fiddling with the number of rows and columns if you change the copy range dimensions later on.

---

PS:

```
dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow() + 1).setValue(value);
```

is missing the column number in `getRange()`